# when migrate data from mysql to postgresql using pgloader show fell through ECASE expression

Tags: postgresql

when I using this command to migrate data from `mysql 5.17.1` to `postgresql 13` in my macOS Catalina 10.15.7:

```
pgloader mysql://root:udUS1y5Mb634ugPD@17.101.228.134:3309/common postgresql://postgres:postgres123456@postgres.dolphin.com:5432/dolphin
```

shows this error:

```
2021-02-02T14:35:18.015000Z LOG pgloader version "3.6.2"
2021-02-02T14:35:18.017000Z LOG Data errors in '/private/tmp/pgloader/'
KABOOM!
FATAL error: Failed to connect to pgsql at "postgres.dolphin.com" (port 5432) as user "postgres": 10 fell through ECASE expression. Wanted one of (0 2 3 4 5 6 7 8).
An unhandled error condition has been signalled:
   Failed to connect to pgsql at "postgres.dolphin.com" (port 5432) as user "postgres": 10 fell through ECASE expression. Wanted one of (0 2 3 4 5 6 7 8).




What I am doing here?

Failed to connect to pgsql at "postgres.dolphin.com" (port 5432) as user "postgres": 10 fell through ECASE expression. Wanted one of (0 2 3 4 5 6 7 8).

(base)
```

I read the [issue](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/issues/1233) has the same problem but still not figure out where is the problem. What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: did you get to find any solution yet?

Comment: No, I did not find a solution.@TalhaMeh

Comment: Information needed 1) What is `password_encryption` set to in `postgresql.conf` for the Postgres 13 server? 2) What are the contents of the `pg_hba.conf` file for the server? 3) Where are you running `pgloader`? 4) What version of `pgloader`? Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: Some solutions to this issue are discussed here https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/issues/1183. Consider that authentication hash algorithm changed from version 12 to 13 (affecting communication between applications consuming the database) of postgresql.